# How to correctly serialize a base class to JSON in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, json, serialization, silverlight-2.0

I have the following structure:

```
class Base
{
}

class Child : Base
{
}
```

When I try to do the following:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Base));
serializer.WriteObject(stream, data);
```

It fails with the error message:

> Type
>   'MyNamespace.Child'
>   with data contract name
>   'Child:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace'
>   is not expected. Add any types not
>   known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.

Does anyone know how to correctly serialize just the child class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the [KnownType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute(VS.95).aspx) (from System.Runtime.Serialization) to the base class for the child class then it will work:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Child))]
class Base
{}

class Child : Base
{}
```

This is needed because the serializer doesn't load your child type when you set it up to serialize the base class (at least this is my understanding).

Comment: Unfortunately the base class is in a separate namespace to the child class. And the base class namespace has no knowledge of the child class namespace.

Comment: Then there is really no way to do this.